# Stuck with nvidia boot screen instead of login

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

I'm new to Linux and today my computer froze while watching youtube. I had to reset using the power button and after the elementary logo when you expect to get the login screen I got stuck with the following nvidia logo-screen:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMZYq.jpg)

I've tried to format my computer, install the drivers from a run package from the official site. But also nvidia-375 and nvidia-381 from the ppa.

The only way not to get stuck on this screen (that i've found) is to uninstall the nvidia drivers using the grub recovery mode > root shell prompt. Then boot the OS by adding nomodeset in front of quiet splash in the Linux line in grub and then boot. This is ofcourse not a solution, so what should I do? It feels like I've tried everything.

I have a gtx 570 GPU

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to switch to a console mode

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> to switch to graphics mode

Enter password try to login, and it will show you login screen again, type you password again and voila